# Values inserted twice mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a bunch of code down here. I am trying to make a chat

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../db/init.php';

$message = $_GET['message'];
if ($message !== '') {
    //Get sessions ID;
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    //==========================Insert new message======================//
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `chatbox` (`id`, `user_id`, `message`) VALUES (NULL, '{$uid}', '{$message}');";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    //===========================Retrive Chat List=====================/
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `chatbox` ORDER BY `id` DESC";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);

    while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $user_id_new = $extract['user_id'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id`='$user_id_new' LIMIT 1";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql2);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo $row['name'] . ": " . $extract['message'] . '<br/>';
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I am using Ajax to insert these values and retrive.

```
function ajax_chat(){
        if(messageform.message.value == ''){
            alert("Please input some message!");
            return;
        }else{
            var message = messageform.message.value;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState ==4&& xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'message.php?message='+message , true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
}
```

My Problem is that values are being inserted even if I have no user input. And another problem is that values are inserted twice, i.e. If I input nothing, a blank string is inserted twice in database. Please help.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the gaping wide open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: @MarcB I'm just testing this on my local machine.

Comment: Please post code for `mysqli_query()`. Also what does `init.php` have?

Comment: Are you using ajax function inside $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Comment: @Kishore the code is in there. That's the only code that I use to update my tables.

Comment: @Manadh I am not using any jQuery code inside.

Comment: Please post code for `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Kishore I said the code that I have is in front of you.